# I have a question about step counter sensor on android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

I am working about android sensors and I am trying to try the software based step counter sensor, but instead of starting from 0, it continues from 512 and I can understand that it writes the number of daily steps as the reason for this, but how can I set it to count from 0 when I am going to make a pedometer application ?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var  sensorManager : SensorManager

    private lateinit var  step_sensor : Sensor

    lateinit var txt : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

        txt = findViewById(R.id.text1)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        sensorManager.registerListener( this , step_sensor , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event : SensorEvent?) {

        txt.text = event?.values?.get(0).toString()
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor : Sensor?, accuracy : Int) {

        if (sensor == step_sensor ) {

            when (accuracy) {

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör yüksek doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör orta doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör düşük doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör çok düşük doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        sensorManager.unregisterListener( this )
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to display a number starting at 0, then simply store the initial value from when *you* want it to start counting and subtract that from every new value (on the same day) before displaying it.

Comment: @GenerousBadger I'm sorry, I didn't understand, could you be more descriptive?

Comment: if the numbers you get from the API are 512, 513, 514, ... but you want to display 0, 1, 2, ... then just remember (store) the first number (512) somewhere and subtract that ever time a number comes in before displaying it.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you, but I have no idea how to do this, but you created a few ideas in my mind, I will handle it somehow, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because the sensor returns the steps since the last reboot of the device.

> A constant describing a step counter sensor.
>
> A sensor of this type returns the number of steps taken by the user
> since the last reboot while activated.

To properly start tracking the amount of steps, you would want to use the first value as the starting value.

```
var initialStepCount = -1
var steps = 0

override fun onSensorChanged(event : SensorEvent?) {
    val sensorStepCount = event?.values?.firstOrNull()

    sensorStepCount?.let {
        if (initialStepCount == -1) {
            initialStepCount = sensorStepCount 
        }

        if (event?.sensor == step_detector) {
            steps = sensorStepCount - initialStepCount
        }
    
        txt.text = step.toString()
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) for a more detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is only one value coming from the step counter sensor, I found a solution as follows. I may have found a temporary solution

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() , SensorEventListener {

    private lateinit var  sensorManager : SensorManager

    private lateinit var  step_detector : Sensor

    var step = -1

    lateinit var txt : TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager

        step_detector = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR)

        txt = findViewById(R.id.text1)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        sensorManager.registerListener( this , step_detector , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event : SensorEvent?) {

        if ( event?.sensor == step_detector ) {

            step ++
        }

        txt.text = step.toString()
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor : Sensor?, accuracy : Int) {

        if (sensor == step_detector ) {

            when (accuracy) {

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör yüksek doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör orta doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör düşük doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE -> {

                        Toast.makeText(this,"Sensör çok düşük doğrulukta çalışmaktadır ." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        sensorManager.unregisterListener( this )
    }

}
```